# Classical definition of number of particles in a volume

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

In "*Relativistic Transport Equation*" by Lindquist (1966), they use the "*classical*" result

$$
\mathrm{d}N = f(x,p,\alpha) \, \mathrm{d}E \, \mathrm{d}\Omega \, \mathrm{d}V
\,,$$
where $N$ is the number of particles in a volume $\mathrm{d}V$ with energy $\mathrm{d}E$ and $\mathrm{d}\Omega$ is the solid angle. $\alpha$ is the vector in the direction of the beam.

I haven't been able to find literature where this formula is explained or deduced and I don't recall it from previous courses... could someone tell me where this formula comes from?

Comment: *where $N$ is the number of particles in a volume $dV$  with energy $dE$...* No, not $N$ but $dN$ is the number of particles in a volume $dV$( point volume at x coordinate) with the energy(depended on momentum p) range from $E(p)$ to $E( p)+dE(p)$.